# Can compile from the commandline but not from a makefile

Tags: compilation, linker, makefile

I am trying to compile a program that consists of a main C file and two auxiliary C++ files. 
*Main.c* depends on *Wrapper.cpp* which in turn depends on *Utility.cpp*. Specifically, Main.c invokes a function *func()* defined in Wrapper.cpp.

The funny issue is that I can compile the program from the command-line but I can't do so from a makefile. I get a linking error "main.o: reference to func() is undefined". This could be primarily because I understand the notion of makefiles but they can get way too complicated!

Here's how I compile from command-line:

```
g++ -c Wrapper.cpp Utility.cpp
gcc -c Main.c Wrapper.cpp 
g++ -o myProg Main.o Wrapper.o Utility.o
```

Here's my makefile:

```
# Rules to produce the targets

all: Main

Main: Utility.o Main.o Wrapper.o
        g++ -o myProg Utility.o Main.o Wrapper.o -lstdc++

# Rules to produce the object files

Utility.o: Utility.cpp
        g++ -c Utility.cpp

Wrapper.o: Wrapper.cpp Utility.cpp
        g++ -c Wrapper.cpp Utility.cpp

Main.o: Main.c Wrapper.cpp
        gcc -c Main.c Wrapper.cpp
```

I know that I might be compiling Utility.cpp and Wrapper.cpp twice but I really don't know how to write the rules to compile. Could someone give me some useful insights. Also please do not give me complicated makefiles because I'm very new to them.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that you are imagining that source files depend on other source files.  That's not true.  You don't need the contents of `Utility.cpp` to compile `Wrapper.cpp` (unless you're doing something strange like `#include`ing source files into other source files).

Similarly, *object files* depend only on the source file that they're compiling, and any headers that source file includes.

And *executable files* depend on all the object files and libraries needed to build the program.

So in the simplest case you'd write (note you don't need to link with `-lstd++` explicitly if you use `g++`:

```
all: Main

Main: Utility.o Main.o Wrapper.o
        g++ -o myProg Utility.o Main.o Wrapper.o

# Rules to produce the object files

Utility.o: Utility.cpp
        g++ -c Utility.cpp

Wrapper.o: Wrapper.cpp
        g++ -c Wrapper.cpp

Main.o: Main.c
        gcc -c Main.c
```

Although this is simple to understand, it really removes most of the power of make.  You could write this makefile to get exactly the same results:

```
CXX = g++
CC = gcc

Main: Main.o Utility.o Wrapper.o
```

That's it, all done.

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback. In the above concise makefile, how to I use the variable CXX and CC?

Comment: You don't need to use them.  Make has a number of built-in rules and those rules use a number of pre-defined variables.  This concise makefile is taking advantage of those built-in rules, one of which tells make how to build a `.o` from a `.cpp`, and another of which tells make how to build a program from a `.o` (with the same prefix name).  Those built-in rules use variables like `CXX`, `CC`, `CPPFLAGS`, `CXXFLAGS`, etc.  So by setting those variables you change how the rule works, without redefining the rule itself.  See the GNU make manual, or run `make -pf/dev/null` to see all the rules.

Comment: Thank you so much for the very useful and easy makefile. I wrote the following makefile XX = g++
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -std=c99
CXXFLAGS = -o myProg
all: Main.o Utility.o Wrapper.o... ...When I compile, I no longer get the original reference undefined error, so that's good. However, no executable is produced i.e. only the object files are produced and are not linked. When I link them on the command-line, the executable is happily produced. Please help me out of this

Comment: It's hard to see exactly what you did in unformatted comments, but in general it's never correct to add the `-o` flag to `CXXFLAGS` or `CFLAGS`.  The `-o` flag is specific for a given target, while those variables are used to build _every_ (C++ / C respectively) target.